# JavaScript Global Variable cannot be accessed inside function

Tags: javascript

The code is as follows :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JS Test</title>
<script>
var con=document.getElementById("con");
    function btn()
    {
        con.innerHTML="Hello";
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="btn()" />
    <div id="con"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not getting the required result. Any one please explain why ?
But I'm getting the result when con is initialized inside the function
ie.

```
function btn()
{
    con=document.getElementById("con");
    con.innerHTML="Hello";
}
```

How to access the global variable declare outside the function? Also tried window.con , but not works..
please explain the reason...

Comment: Check the value of *con*, it will be *null*, which means it has been assigned a value and is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running the script in the head so the DOM element doesn't exist yet. Try moving your script to the footer and you should be golden.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the script at the bottom.

Indeed, when `document.getElementById("con");` is not declared in a function, the targeted element is about to be retrieved directly but doesn't exist yet.